# How to fix periodic and unexplained "access denied" Windows Server 2008r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions

There is a remote desktop server (also file server) that works just fine for almost exactly 14 days give or take a day or two. Then, it just locks everyone out with "access denied". It can be resolved by restarting the server.

The "access denied" not only applies to RD logon. SSRS running on the server is also unable to access the SQL Server DB. However, network shares and mapping drives works just fine.

The event logs only show "access denied" and it isn't clear to a team of certified professionals what is happening.

It makes me wonder if there is some sort of timeout in the access control subsystem that expires and cannot be reset without a full restart. Hopefully, there is someone in the community that may be able to assist with this.

Server has two IPs on different MACs.

Typical log messages around the time just prior and after the "Access denied":

DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX using any of the configured protocols.

The Remote Desktop Session Host server could not contact the Remote Desktop license server XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX. Ensure that the Remote Desktop Licensing service is running on the license server, that the license server is accepting network requests, and that the license server is registered in WINS and DNS.

The following fatal alert was generated: 10. The internal error state is 1203 (source Schannel).

A duplicate name has been detected on the TCP network. The IP address of the computer that sent the message is in the data. Use nbtstat -n in a command window to see which name is in the Conflict state.

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

A process serving application pool 'OLAP' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3972'. The process exit code was '0xc0000005'. (source WAS)

Comment: Domain join? And having only the dc dns ? Check eventlog too

Comment: Event log showed some issues with dns etc. However, nslookup works for the addresses shown as having errors in the eventlog.

Comment: Do you have multiple dns listed for the nic?

Comment: A cloned computer? Another computer got the same netbios name, and surelly tried to update the server dns record

Comment: Just seen that it got 2 IP. 2 IP on same NIC, or two NIC with an IP on each ?

Comment: Two NIC with an IP each, secondary IP has DNS/WINS. Should there be a naming conflict, what I don't understand is how this issue seems to show symptoms on a regular periodic basis of about 2 weeks.

Comment: Yes, I would remove the DNS/WINS config of that NIC. You can create a static entry in the DNS to prevent a problem, for the WINS I would go look at the records too. For the two week period it's strange.